# How to set None to OverrideActionProperty in CfnWebACL (AWS CDK WAFv2)

Tags: c#, aws-cdk

I am trying to create a AWS WAF by AWS CDK using C#.
Since the regional WebACL applys the managed rules such as `AWSManagedRulesAdminProtectionRuleSet`, `OverrideAction` is necessary to the rule.

The CloudFormation template should be `"None": {}`.
But I could not create the parameter from `OverrideActionProperty` instance.

Now my code is

```
OverrideAction = new OverrideActionProperty( )
{
    None = null
}
```

It create no `None` attribute.
I also try `None = new object()`, but occurs the error -
`Could not infer JSII type for .NET type 'Object' (Parameter 'type')`.

What should I set to the `None` object?

Answer (score 2):

I found that `None = new Dictionary<string, object> { }` is the answer.
Thanks.